# Separate multiple bar in horizontal bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

So i have the following graph
[image]

Sample data similar to what formulates it

```
{'0-Engajados': {'carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms': 2072.0,
  'site': 2748.0,
  'Soma Total': 9367.0},
 '9.2-Finalizado': {'carrinho-abandonado-ecommerce-sms': 176.0,
  'site': 106.0,
  'Soma Total': 684.0}}
```

Source df code:

```
eng = camp_df.loc['0-Engajados'].sort_values(ascending=True)
fin = camp_df.loc['9.2-Finalizado'].sort_values(ascending=True)
source = pd.concat([eng,fin],axis=1)
ind = source.index
```

Base code

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(ind,eng,label='Engajado')
ax.barh(ind,fin,label='Finalizado')
ax.legend()
fig.set_figheight(15)
fig.set_figwidth(15)
```

I am having a little trouble putting the blue graph under the red graph would appreciate some help, newbee to matplotlib btw

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "offset"?

Comment: Well make it so the blue graph is under the red graph, dissociated. Not together

Comment: pass different values of `ind` for both bars

Comment: Humm if they are string values, how would i pass different values. Check reedit for understanding